# Deep copy of an array of integers, using only pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I need to write a function that makes a deep copy of an array of integers, 
using only pointer arithmetic (i.e. cannot use array-element syntax like orig[i]).

The first argument is the array to copy, and its length is specified by the second argument.

Here is what I have so far:

```
int* copyArray(const int *orig, int size) {

  int *copy = malloc(size * sizeof *copy);

  int **toReturn = &copy;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, orig++, copy++) {
    *copy = *orig;
  }

  return *toReturn;

}

int main () {

  int testArray[3] = {1, 2, 3};
  int *testptr = testArray;

  int *copied = copyArray(testptr, 3);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    printf("%d %p", testArray[i], &testArray[i]);
    printf("\n");

  }

  printf("\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    printf("%d %p", copied[i], &copied[i]);
    printf("\n");

  }

return 0;
}
```

This isn't getting me the right results... 
The result I get from this is:

```
1 0x7ffce0ff6fd0
2 0x7ffce0ff6fd4
3 0x7ffce0ff6fd8

0 0xe1301c
0 0xe13020
0 0xe13024
```

whereas it should be:

```
1 0x7ffce0ff6fd0
2 0x7ffce0ff6fd4
3 0x7ffce0ff6fd8

1 0xe1301c
2 0xe13020
3 0xe13024
```

I'm new to pointers and memory allocation...
What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Problem fixed!

Look at my answer, or the other answers that work as well.

Comment: You're incrementing `copy`, so when you return it, it points to the end of the array. Also, you're allocating only 3 bytes of memory; it should be `malloc(size * sizeof *copy)`. Third problem found: use `size` in the for loop in `copyArray()`, not `3`.

Comment: Thanks @potrzebie! I made the changes you recommended... but I'm still getting the same result. I'm not sure if I made the right change to the return statement though. Please have a look! UPDATED.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace You can't use the line `copy++`.  That changes the value you return.  The value of `copy` that you get from `malloc` needs to be returned *unchanged* from your `copyArray` function.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I posted some updates that I think address your concern, yet I'm still getting the same result. :( Please look at the updated question.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace You're getting too complex. Keep it simple.

Comment: You're returning the end of the array, you need to return what `copy` pointed to before you did `copy++`.  Also `toReturn` is redundant, what you have now is the same as `return copy;`.

Comment: @potrzebie +1 on the screen name.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Change `copyArray` to something like

```
int *copyArray( const int *orig, size_t size )
{
    int *copy = malloc(size * sizeof( *copy ) );

    for ( size_t ii = 0; ii < size; ii++ )
    {
        copy[ ii ] = orig[ ii ];
    }
    return( copy );
}
```

Stylistically, I personally like `ii` instead of `i`.  It's hard to search for `i`.  And `size_t` is a better choice than `int` for something that's used to describe the size of something.

You probably should add some error checking should `malloc` return `NULL`.

And, without indexing the pointers (because simple code is to be banned?!?)

```
int *copyArray( const int *orig, size_t size )
{
    int *copy = malloc(size * sizeof( *copy ) );

    memcpy( copy, orig, size * sizeof( *copy ) );
    return( copy );
}
```

That's likely faster anyway.  Proper header inclusion is left as an exersize for the reader... ;-)

It still needs error checking, though.

Comment: Thanks! This will most probably work, but I am not allowed to use array-element syntax like copy[ii] as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace *I am not allowed to use array-element syntax like copy[ii] as I mentioned in the question.*  OK, I won't ask *why*.  Simple fix on the way....

Comment: Thanks again, @AndrewHenie!

Answer (score 1):

This is a working version of the copyArray function:

```
int* copyArray(const int *orig, int size) {

  int *copy = malloc(size * sizeof *copy);

  int *toReturn = copy;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, orig++, copy++) {
    *copy = *orig;
  }

  return toReturn;

}
```